# how to convert xml file to a string and write it to another file in xml format?

Tags: java, file-io, xml-parsing

i have a requirement in that i need to convert the xml file in to a string and then write it to another file as valid xml format.

i tried few logics but all of those are failed to write string to xml file format as it is always taking as XML tags but not as a string.

for example my code was

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Students>
    <Student_Name>Srinivas</Student_Name>
    <Student_FullName>Srinivas_Kumar</Student_FullName>
    <DOB>1992-09-25</DOB>
    <FlatNo>#04, 8th main</FlatNo>
    <Locality>Gandhi Road</Locality>
</Students>
```

expected output should be like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns0:message>
<Students><Student_Name>Srinivas</Student_Name><Student_FullName>Srinivas_Kumar</Student_FullName><DOB>1992-09-25</DOB><FlatNo>#04, 8th main</FlatNo><Locality>Gandhi Road</Locality></Students>
</ns0:message>
```

please help me in this.

one of my logic is

```
public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException { 
    FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream("path"); 
    FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream("path"); 
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fin)); 
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(fout)); 
    String initialtag = . 
    String endtag = . 
    String line ; 
    bw.write(initialtag); 
    while((line = br.readLine()) != null) { 
        line.replaceAll("<","&lt"); 
        line.replaceAll(">","&gt"); 
        bw.write(line); 
    } 
        bw.write(endtag); 
        bw.close(); 
}
```

Comment: Let's see what code you've tried so far.

Comment: public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException 
    {
 FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream("path");
 FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream("path");
 BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fin));
 BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(fout));
 String initialtag = .
 String endtag = .
 String line ;
 bw.write(initialtag);
     while((line = br.readLine()) != null)
         {
     line.replaceAll("<","&lt"); 
      line.replaceAll(">","&gt"); 
          bw.write(line);
         }
  bw.write(endtag);       
 bw.close(); 
    }

Comment: this is one of my logics i used, help me to code this as per the requirement.

Comment: Please edit your post and put the code in it.

Comment: i edited it & included

Comment: That code doesn't compile.... `String initialtag = .` and `String endtag = .` fails.

Comment: it has some intial and end tags i just skipped that

Comment: Does this run? Do you get any errors?

Comment: yes it runs with no errors. as i said it was converting to string and writing to  other file in xml format but the string was appearing as a xml lines but not as a string

Comment: give me some suggestions so that i can code my self.